# SW clock drift problem

Tags: linux, time

i got a problem: my linux software clock seems so have a big drift. In order to correct this (and to make ntpd work) I ran adjtimex. And adjtimex "meassured" a drift over -1700s/day and corrected this drift.

Of course, this totally wrong, but now the software clock tries to compensate this drift and is out of order.

How can I "reset" the software clock? I can't find any files/tools to reset the drift, adjtimex has introduced.

Deleting the adjtimex conf files won't help.

Thanks a lot, I need a working clock :D

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, is your BIOS clock correct ?

Second, are you able to use ntp ? ntp would fix alot of these problems, but bear in mind it wont adjust the clock in one step, it moves it inline with the correct time over a few runs, depending how far out it was.

I dont know about adjtimex, but it sounds like your battery has run out on motherboard. Might be wrong but thats where id start

Comment: Thanks for your ideas... some more Information: the RTC (=BIOS) clock doesn't affect the software clock as long as the PC is running. And it is set correct. And ntp won't help, because it can't sync, if the SW clock has too much drift :(

Comment: Oh right, the sw clock is going out of sync that fast ?! Hmmmm, right timezone ?

Answer (score 0):

Is it an ASUS mainboard by chance? There have been a batch of ASUS mainboards with timing issues which get fixed by a bios upgrade.

(Use `dmidecode` as root to get an idea of the bios vendor without having to reboot the system).

Comment: It is a Asus P4P800-X. Is this one of the broken ones?

Comment: Might be, given the age. Check the current bios version and the notes for bios updates on the Asus websites.